# Dapr CLI not Responding to CTRL+C in Makefile Target

Tags: bash, azure, shell, makefile, dapr

I'm encountering an issue with a Makefile target that uses the Dapr CLI to run a process. Here's the relevant part of the Makefile:

```
start:
   .. other commands
   @dapr run -f ./filtered_dapr.yaml --log-as-json
```

While the Dapr CLI starts successfully, attempting to stop the process using CTRL+C doesn't produce the expected result, and the process does not exit. Interestingly, when I run the same Dapr command directly in the CLI, it closes the process as anticipated. I've also experimented with running the command in a shell script, but encountered the same problem.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue, and if so, have you found a workaround or solution? I'm open to suggestions on how to address this CTRL+C handling problem with the Dapr CLI within a Makefile context. Thanks in advance for any insights!